# Scala String trick or method that inserts a new line or other character each time an "|" is placed

Tags: scala, string-formatting

First of all I would like to apologise for how vague this question may seem, but at this point, I have not found any information on the matter.

Some time ago a colleague was talking to me about monoids and a JSON Parser, then he showed me a way of constructing Strings that looked more or less like this (Based on my poor memory):

```
strangeMethodOrTrick = {

  | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  | consectetur adipiscing elit
  | sed do eiusmod
  | tempor incididunt

}.toString
```

At one point he mentioned that, every time the "|" character was typed in, it meant a line break was placed at the end of each line once the final String was created.

Apologies again for not providing more information about the subject, today I asked my colleague about this but he said he doesn't remember such thing like that or anything related to it.

For my part I haven't found any information either, I only remember what the code looked like and so far I haven't found that in the Scala documentation.

I would appreciate if anyone knows about this tactic and, if you know the name or how I could find more information about it.

For anything else, I wish you guys a very happy new year!

Comment: Well, the behavior of `|` acting is a line delimiter is actually part of the language as you can see [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/two-notes-about-strings.html). However, and no. I haven't tested this, you should certainly be able to use two different characters simply by doing your own string processing like `class StringWrapper(s: String) { the override def toString = myStr.split("#").join("\n") }`. Maybe clean that up with an implicit but that should do it

Comment: @AluanHaddad I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Anytime sir, glad I could help. I did have a typo though I just realized. It needs to be `mkString` instead of `join`. It's been awhile since I've written Scala sadly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a built-in feature and it doesn't insert new line breaks. The standard library provides an extension method for strings [`stripMargin`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.8/scala/collection/StringOps.html#stripMargin:String) that strips any leading whitespace followed by `|` from every line of a string.

```
val str = 
  """|multiple lines
     |in one string
     |with stripMargin""".stripMargin
```

Note that the newlines are already part of the string before calling `stripMargin` because I constructed a multi line string with the help of triple quotes `"""`. All `stripMargin` does is delete the leading whitespace and the `|`.

As you can see in the [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.8/scala/collection/StringOps.html#stripMargin(marginChar:Char):String) there is a `stripMargin` method that you can call with another character than `|` if you want to, e.g. `stripMargin('#')`.

Comment: This is it! I was confused about the usage of the triple quotes with the stripMargin method that you just mentioned; maybe this is why my friend had no idea what I was talking about. Anyway, thank you for refreshing my memory, have a nice day 